# can't equalize variable to another one retrieved from localStorage [Vuejs]

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, local-storage

i'm working on a website where there's a dialog (from the vuetify library) binded to a variable called "tutorial", inside that dialog there's a button to close the dialog and a checkbox, if i check the ckeckbox before closing, i set a variable on localstorage as "false", and at the created lifehook i try to equalize the variable that the dialog is binded to, to the variable in local storage, but it doesn't work. The component here:

```
<template>
  <v-containter>
    <v-dialog v-model="tutorial" max-width="500px">
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            Tutorial
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            Some tutorial text here
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
           <v-btn color="error" @click="closeTutorial">Close</v-btn>
           <v-checkbox v-model="dontShowAgain" label="Don't show this again"></v-checkbox>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
const STORAGE_KEY = 'tutorial';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tutorial: true,
      dontShowAgain: false,
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) === !null) {
      this.tutorial = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeTutorial() {
      this.tutorial = false;
      if (this.dontShowAgain) {
        localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, this.tutorial)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As long as i can see in my localStorage, the value IS actually setted when i close the dialog with the checkbox checked, but nothing happens at the created() method when i try to equalize the variable in the component to the variable in localStorage, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try before `localStorage.setItem` convert value to json via `JSON.stringify()` and when you get from localStorage, apply `JSON.parse()` to ensure correct type of value

Comment: Great! this worked perfectly, put it as answer so i can vote it as better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try before `localStorage.setItem` convert value to json via `JSON.stringify()` and when you get from localStorage, apply `JSON.parse()` to ensure correct type of value.